# Should i use Cloudflare Accelerated Mobile Links option if I already have amp implemented on my Website since 2015?

Tags: wordpress, dns, cdn, amp-html, cloudflare

I have WordPress Website with Google AMP already implemented and working.

Currently, I transfered to CloudFlare and saw the AMP feature.

What should I do now? Should I enable it or not?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's really up to the use cases you want to cater and user traffic sources.
Eg. is your primary traffic coming from organic search? Your site's URLs should have been cached and served from AMP Cache already.
Eg. do a lot of users open your site's URLs in a webview? maybe you can give Cloudflare a shot here?

This article might help:
https://antonyagnel.com/how-to-enable-accelerated-mobile-links-in-cloudflare/
"Cloudflare’s Accelerated Mobile Links is actually powered by the official AMP project. What Cloudflare actually does, in this case, is – it loads AMP enabled external links inside of a viewing window, within the same tab. This in comparison is different from what Google does. Google displays the AMP version of a site only when the search query comes from a mobile device through Google search."